# "Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped" on Android Nexus 6 emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

When testing my 2D game on the Nexus 6 emulator, the app launches and works fine the first time.  But when I close out of the app and try to reopen it, I get a "Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped" and the emulator crashes.  This only happens on the Nexus 6 emulator, on other older AVDs the app reopens fine.  Nothing shows up in Logcat when this happens.

I was wondering if anyone knew why this happens and only on the Nexus 6 emulator.  I have suspected the following culprits but I am not sure:

1. Out of memory - I do not release any of the bitmap resources used in the game, should I be doing this and if so, should it be from the `surfaceDestroyed()` method?
2. A threading issue - perhaps the thread is not being properly shut down or restarted?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 15):

Well I figured it out, turns out if I increase the RAM and heap space in the  AVD advanced settings slightly I do not have this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what values you actually used.

Comment: I had this problem too.  I used 1536 for ram and increased the default 64MB heap to 128MB and the emulator quit crashing.

Comment: For me is was only the heap size that needed the increase. Was initially 64 GB so I doubled it to 128 GB which resolved the error. My RAM is only 512 MB. Increasing it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Even this problem , affects the real devices , how can we get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

On Mac here was the default install location for me:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools
```

Then in that folder I ran

```
android avd
```

Then I set the following settings
RAM 1536 mb
VM Heap 64 mb

Internal Storage 768mb
SD Card 768mb

Comment: What of us who the problem on the Real device My Real device said **The System UI has stopped Unfortunately**  , , I just took it to the carl care center to recover the launcher , what is the solution for that please ?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris You should ask a new question in that case since this question only relates to the emulator.